# Batch renaming file names including a part of old file name

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh, rename

I have a following list of files;

```
11F.fastq.gz
11R.fastq.gz
12F.fastq.gz
12R.fastq.gz
```

I'd like to rename these file names to the following;

```
11_S11_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
11_S11_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
12_S12_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
12_S12_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I tried `reanme` as follows

```
rename 's/F.fastq/_S_L001_R1_001.fastq/' *.gz
rename 's/R.fastq/_S_L001_R2_001.fastq./' *.gz
```

but I dont quite know how to add file numbers (11 and 12 in this case) after "S".  Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Perl's `rename` commandline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574), you can capture the variable part (`(...)`) and use back references (`$1`):

```
rename -n 's/(\d+)F\.fastq/$1_S$1_L001_R1_001.fastq/' *F.fastq.gz
rename -n 's/(\d+)R\.fastq/$1_S$1_L001_R2_001.fastq/' *R.fastq.gz
```

Remove the `-n` if you're happy with the output.

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` has its own builtin batch renaming tool: `zmv` available as an autoloadable function.

```
autoload -Uz zmv
typeset -A map=(F 1 R 2)
zmv -n '(<->)([FR])(.fastq.gz)' '${1}_S${1}_L001_R$map[$2]_001$3'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

Or using a scalar `map=FR` and use the index of the letter in that string for the replacement:

```
map=FR
zmv -n "(<->)([$map])(.fastq.gz)" '${1}_S${1}_L001_R$map[(Ie)$2]_001$3'
```